# Condition on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, case

I want to create a code that run on a data frame based on conditions form another data frame.
The code should do this: if column 1 has A and type1, then give it a score.
the condition data frame is something similar to this:

```
df1<-data.frame(Gene1=c("A","B", "C","D"),
                   type1=c(50,40,20,10),
                   type2=c(20,30,20,10),
                   type3=c(5,50,30,10))
```

and my data looks like this:

```
df2<-data.frame(Gene1=c("A","B", "C","D"),
                types=c("type1","type2","type3","type4"))
```

the output should look like this :

```
df.output<-data.frame(Gene1=c("A","B", "C","D"),
                types=c("type1","type2","type3","type4"),
                score=c(50,30,30,10))
```

So the conditions is based on 2 columns, I used case_when but it did not work, something like this:

```
df<- df1%>%
mutate(score=case_when(Gene1=="A"& types=="type1~ 50,
Gene1=="B"& types=="type2~ 30,
Gene1=="C"& types=="type3~ 30,
Gene1=="D"& types=="type4~ 10,
 TRUE ~ 0))
```

it is not working, also if I  want case_when to ignore the order of the conditions so it matches all the conditions regardless there order what should i do?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df_output <- df1 |>
  left_join(df2, by = "Gene1") |> 
  mutate(score = case_when(
      Gene1 == "A" & types == "type1" ~ 50,
      Gene1 == "B" & types == "type2" ~ 30,
      Gene1 == "C" & types == "type3" ~ 30,
      Gene1 == "D" & types == "type4" ~ 10,
      TRUE ~ 0)) |>
  select(Gene1, types, score)
```

Comment: Thank you what about the ignoring the condition order for case when?

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi, from what I understand, the code is already set up to work independently of the order of conditions

Comment: This may look like a programatical solution, but this is actually just hard-coding the values in the score column

Answer (score 3):

If you `pivot_longer` your first data frame, then you can simply `right_join` it to your second data frame, matching by `Gene1` and `types`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Gene1, names_to = 'types') %>%
  right_join(df2, by = c('Gene1', 'types'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Gene1 types value
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A     type1    50
#> 2 B     type2    30
#> 3 C     type3    30
#> 4 D     type4    NA
```

Note that there is no `type4` in `df1`, so the last row of your output should have a value of `NA`, unless there are additional rules you have not specified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Reshape df1, `merge` df2.

```
reshape2::melt(df1, 'Gene1', variable.name='types') |> merge(df2)
#   Gene1 types value
# 1     A type1    50
# 2     B type2    30
# 3     C type3    30
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Gene1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), type1 = c(50, 40, 
20, 10), type2 = c(20, 30, 20, 10), type3 = c(5, 50, 30, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Gene1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), types = c("type1", 
"type2", "type3", "type4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If df1 has a column for every "type", including type4 (not included in the example), we can use `get`.

**data**

```
df1<-data.frame(Gene1=c("A","B", "C","D"),
                type1=c(50,40,20,10),
                type2=c(20,30,20,10),
                type3=c(5,50,30,10),
                type4=c(1,2,3,4))
> df1
  Gene1 type1 type2 type3 type4
1     A    50    20     5     1
2     B    40    30    50     2
3     C    20    20    30     3
4     D    10    10    10     4
```

**answer**

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2) |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(score = get(types)) |> 
    select(-c(type1:type4)) |> 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Gene1 types score
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 A     type1    50
2 B     type2    30
3 C     type3    30
4 D     type4     4
```